# Django : Validate data by querying the database in a model form (using custom clean method)

Tags: django, forms, customization

I am trying to create a custom cleaning method which look in the db if the value of one specific data exists already and if yes raises an error.
I'm using a model form of a class (subsystem) who is inheriting from an other class (project).
I want to check if the sybsystem already exists or not when i try to add a new one in a form.

I get project name in my view function.

```
class SubsytemForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
        exclude = ('project_name')

    def clean(self,project_name):

        cleaned_data = super(SubsytemForm, self).clean(self,project_name)
        form_subsystem_name = cleaned_data.get("subsystem_name")

        Subsystem.objects.filter(project__project_name=project_name)
        subsystem_objects=Subsystem.objects.filter(project__project_name=project_name)
        nb_subsystem = subsystem_objects.count()

        for i in range (nb_subsystem):
            if (subsystem_objects[i].subsystem_name==form_subsystem_name):
                msg = u"Subsystem already existing"
                self._errors["subsystem_name"] = self.error_class([msg])

            # These fields are no longer valid. Remove them from the
            # cleaned data.
            del cleaned_data["subsystem_name"]
        return cleaned_data
```

My view function :

```
def addform(request,project_name):
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form=form.save(commit=False)
        form.project_id=Project.objects.get(project_name=project_name).id 
        form.clean(form,project_name)
        form.save()
```

This is not working and i don't know how to do.
I have the error : clean() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

My model :

```
class Project(models.Model):
project_name = models.CharField("Project name", max_length=20)

Class Subsystem(models.Model):
subsystem_name = models.Charfield("Subsystem name", max_length=20)
projects = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Comment: Some kind of stacktrace might be useful. Also I'm not sure if it's ok to delete a key from the cleaned_data array. Maybe just set it to null or an empty string ? Then in your is_valid method you add project_name to the form.clean method, but I don't see it being defined anywhere in your code ?

Comment: It was just a mistake. I want to check if the subsystem name entered in the form is already used, because it has to be unique.

Comment: I use the is_valid method which is a default method provided by django to check if the data is correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with this code.

Firstly, you're not supposed to call `clean` explicitly. Django does it for you automatically when you call `form.is_valid()`. And because it's done automatically, you can't pass extra arguments. You need to pass the argument in when you instantiate the form, and keep it as an instance variable which your clean code can reference.

Secondly, the code is actually only validating a single field. So it should be done in a specific `clean_fieldname` method - ie `clean_subsystem_name`. That avoids the need for mucking about with `_errors` and deleting the unwanted data at the end.

Thirdly, if you ever find yourself getting a count of something, iterating through a range, then using that index to point back into the original list, you're doing it wrong. In Python, you should always iterate through the actual thing - in this case, the queryset - that you're interested in. However, in this case that is irrelevant anyway as you should query for the actual name directly in the database and check if it exists, rather than iterating through checking for matches.

So, putting it all together:

```
class SubsytemForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
        exclude = ('project_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project_name = kwargs.pop('project_name', None)
        super(SubsystemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_subsystem_name(self):
        form_subsystem_name = self.cleaned_data.get("subsystem_name")

        existing = Subsystem.objects.filter(
                       project__project_name=self.project_name,
                       subsytem_name=form_subsystem_name
                   ).exists()

        if existing:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"Subsystem already existing")

        return form_subsystem_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand my  mistakes, but it still doesn't work !! In fact, it is not getting project_name, It just set project_name as None. Any idea ?

Comment: Well, you've excluded `project_name` from the form. But I don't understand the relationship between `project_name` and `subsystem_name`. Which is the actual model field name?

Comment: I added the model in the question. I excluded project_name from the form because I don't want the user to choose which project to map with the subsystem. I map it in my view. I think the best is not to exclude project_name but to init it in my form with value (populate the project_name field using a queryset ?). And I set this field as hidden. What do you think ?

Comment: No, doing it in the view is the correct thing to do. Just save your form with `obj=form.save(commit=False)`, assign `obj.project_name = project_name`, then `obj.save()`.

Comment: Now I have no idea what you're asking, I'm afraid. My code in the answer shows how to check the subsystem.

Comment: I just wanted to display the error inside the form and not in an other page.

Answer (score 0):

When you do form=form.save(commit=False) you store a Subsystem instance in the variable form but the clean method is defined in SubsystemForm. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I do that to map my subsystem instance to the project.

Comment: but with form.clean(form,project_name) you are not calling the clean method you have defined in SubsystemForm

Comment: First of all you shouldn't add a second argument to the clean method as this method gets called automatically by form.is_valid(). and there project_name is not set of course. you could move the clean method to the Subsystem model if you want to reset a field depending on the values set in other fields. anyway, isn't setting the model field subsystem_name to unique what you are looking for?

Comment: No, because you can have the same subsytem in Project A and in Project B, but in one Project, Subsystem must be unique.